# Understanding for loop update variable

Tags: python, for-loop

```
d1 = {}
d1["One"] = "Uno"
d1["Two"] = "Dos"
d2 = {}
d2["One"] = 1
d2["Two"] = 2
d2["Three"] = 3
for x in d1.keys():
    for y in d2.keys():
        if x != y:
            d1[x] = d2[x] + d2[x]
print(d1)
```

I am trying to understand the out come with the nested for loops but get confused at the part where the Item "One" does not = "Three" in the first iteration so then shouldn't it update the value in one to d1["One"] = "6"

Comment: You never use `d2[y]` in your code, and `x` can only be `"One"` or `"Two"`, so where would `6` come from?

Comment: @samwise So I see that 'One' gets updated to 2 but shouldn't it then run the next check which would be does d1["One"] = d2["Three"] as in the if statement x != y so then it would take value of "Three" which is = 3 and do d1[x] = 3 + 3?

Comment: Isn't it taking the value from the d2[] where it is not equal?

Comment: It's taking *a* value from `d2`...

Comment: Since `x` is `"One"`, `d1[x] = d2[x] + d2[x]` is `d1["One"] = d2["One"] + d2["One"]`, so no `"Three"` here. I guess what you wanted was `d1[x] = d2[y] + d2[y]`

Answer (score 1):

A useful way to debug small programs like this is to add `print` calls to show exactly what your code is doing.

```
for x in d1.keys():
    for y in d2.keys():
        if x != y:
            print(f"setting d1[{x!r}] to d2[{x!r}]*2 ({d2[x]*2}) because {x!r} != {y!r}")
            d1[x] = d2[x] + d2[x]
print(d1)
```

prints:

```
setting d1['One'] to d2['One']*2 (2) because 'One' != 'Two'
setting d1['One'] to d2['One']*2 (2) because 'One' != 'Three'
setting d1['Two'] to d2['Two']*2 (4) because 'Two' != 'One'
setting d1['Two'] to d2['Two']*2 (4) because 'Two' != 'Three'
{'One': 2, 'Two': 4}
```

As you can see, even on the iterations where `y` is `'Three'` the `3` value from `d2` is never used.